# "Constructor of inner class can be called only with receiver of containing class" when I create inner classs instance in constructor

Tags: kotlin, constructor, inner-classes

I have a class

```
data classOuter (
    val str: String = "fOo"
    ...
    val innerClassInstance: InnerClass= InnerClass(),
) {

  ...
  inner class InnerClass {
     fun foo () {     
         return str.toLowerCase()
     }
  }
}
```

But I get an error:

```
Constructor of inner class InnerClass can be called only with receiver of containing class
```

Is there way to avoid it ?

Comment: Do you *understand* what the error is telling you? Why do you think this should work in the first place?

Comment: Usually, when a class has a reference to a instance of an inner class defined within, it would be an instance bound to itself. It therefore would not make sense to try to pass it an instance of the inner class to its constructor.

Comment: Are you really looking for an *inner* class (which holds a reference to an instance of the enclosing class) or just a nested class?

Comment: I need acces to str from inner class so it should be inner

Comment: Not really, if you just need `str` you could explicitly pass it to `InnerClass`'s constructor instead of (implicitly) passing the whole outer class instance

Comment: And the second question comes down to @Tenfour04's comment: why do you need to pass an `InnerClass`'s instance to the *constructor* of `OuterClass`? Would it make sense to receive an instance of `InnerClass` from the caller? Note that it could potentially point to a completely different `OuterClass` instance.

Comment: You should first clarify what you want `val innerClassInstance: InnerClass = InnerClass()` to *mean*. As it is, that does not make sense. What instance of `Outer` do you want to create an `InnerClass` out of? And whatever your answer is, ask yourself where that instance of `Outer` comes from.

Comment: *Note that it could potentially point to a completely different OuterClass instance.* - yeah actually, scratch that. It woud *have to* point to a different instance of `OuterClass`, because the one that is being constructed is by definition not constructed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is chicken and egg problem. [Inner class object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html#inner-classes) refers parent class object, which is not yet constructed at this point (at the point of passing parameters to the constructor of parent class).

You may employ lazy initialisation of nested class object, so it would be initialised at the time parent class object already exists. Like:

```
data class classOuter (
    val str: String = "foo"
) {
  val innerClassInstance: InnerClass by lazy { this.InnerClass() }

  inner class InnerClass {
     fun foo () : String {     
         return str.toLowerCase()
     }
  }
}

fun main() {
    println(classOuter("bar").innerClassInstance.foo())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html#inner-classes) Inner classes carry a reference to an object of the outer class, so you need at first initiate the Outer class. As you are trying to pass `InnerClass` to the constructor of the `OuterClass` it will cause `java.lang.StackOverflowError` in the end.

If you remove `InnerClass` out of constructor it will work:

```
fun main() {
    val innerClass = OuterClass().InnerClass()
    val outerClass = OuterClass()
    innerClass.foo()
    println(outerClass.name)
}

class OuterClass {

    val name: String = "Foo"

    inner class InnerClass {

        fun foo() {
            println("Nested")
            println(name)
        }
    }
}
```